# Job location overlaps with "within x km" for some queries

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, design

The location searchbar looks broken to me for some search queries, the specified location and the "within x km" seem to overlap:

[image: broken location searchbar]

Using following query: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=Ebersberg%2C+Deutschland&d=20&u=Km

Used browser: Firefox 64.0, was also able to reproduce with Chrome 71 after fiddling a bit with the window size.

Comment: I'm wondering why the distance string is not right-aligned to the arrow to begin with...